# Checkbox onclick and onchange event called twice, please see simple example

Tags: jquery-mobile

If i comment out the jquery.mobile...js file, this works fine,  with it included, everytime i click the checkbox, the onclick event fires twice.  Same is true for onchange event.  Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function tester() { alert("I get called twice on click"); }
    </script>
    <input id="abc" name="myCheckbox" onchange="tester()" type="checkbox" value="true" />

    <label for="myCheckbox">Click me</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is malformed. The `<label>` tag points to a non-existent id. It points to "myCheckbox" but the id of your input tag is "abc". This change fixes your issue and the markup is correctly enhanced.

```
<input id="abc" name="myCheckbox" onchange="tester()"
    type="checkbox" value="true" />
<label for="abc">Click me</label>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I spent 4 hours pulling my hair out googling and trying different things.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design, since both events are happening. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/T3qmG/

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checkbox Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h2>Checkbox Test</h2>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-choice-1" />
                    <label for="checkbox-choice-1">Click me</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkbox-choice-1").click(function(){
        alert("Click event triggerd.");
    });
    $("#checkbox-choice-1").change(function(){
        alert("Change event triggerd.");
    });
});
```

I would advise separating your script code if possible. You can a function to one or both events.